# HTML5 Video - multidevice, multibrowser, no sound

Tags: html, video, html5-video

Currently i have some problems implemeting a video with the HTML5-Video-Tag. I implemented the video in the formats .mp4, .ogg and .webm to support all common browsers.

My first problem is now that the video is displayed on all browsers but the IE. I yet tried to add the MIME-Types in the .htaccess file but that brought no improvement.

The next problem is that the video is displayed normally on mobile devices but on desktop devices there is no sound. I'm nearly despeiring :D

Is there someone that had the same problems or could give me a hint? I woukd be very very thankful.

Kind regards

Edit: Code example

```
    <video width="100%" height="100%" controls>
<source src="intro.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<source src="intro.ogg" type="video/ogg">
<source src="intro.webm" type="video/webm">
Some text....
</video>
```

Comment: You need to add some code and more details (e.g.: what version of IE is not working?) to your question. Otherwise, it's almost impossible to know what is going wrong

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll do this as soon as possible.

Comment: Posted an example code that should look like mine :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please specify Internet Explorer version. For instance, it's IE6, HTML5 video player won't work at all.

Second, the problem can be in MP4 file itself. The file needs to be encoded with h.264 codec. Please check the MP4 file media data. For example, you can do it with MediaInfo software.